# Убрать симметричные индексы в массиве

Tags: python, массивы, списки

Пытаюсь создать список состоящий из массива из двух элементов.
Как убрать симметричные массивы?
Например: есть `[1,2]`, как исключить `[2,1]`?

```
dbl=[]
for i in range(1,21):
    d=[0,0]
    for j in range(1,21):
        if j!=i :
            d=[i,j]           
            dbl.append(d)
print(dbl)
```

Comment: Нужно ли исключить [1, 1], [2, 2] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно внутренний цикл начинать не с `1`, а с `i`:

```
for j in range(i, 21):
```

Ещё лучше начинать с `i + 1`, чтобы убрать проверку на равенство:

```
for j in range(i + 1, 21):
    d=[i,j]           
    dbl.append(d)
```

Также можно воспользоваться методом `combinations` из модуля `itertools`:

```
from itertools import combinations
dbl = list(combinations(range(1, 21), 2))  # Указываем множество, из которого нужно брать элементы, и длину комбинаций
print(dbl)
```

P.S. Если нужны комбинации в том числе с одинаковыми элементами, следует использовать метод `combinations_with_replacement` из того же модуля.